# Binary to Hexadecimal converter

Tags: python, binary, hex

I have written a code to try and convert a 4-bit binary number into Hexadecimal. Only thing is, when I type a value that begins with a '1' it comes up with the conversion, whereas if I type a value that starts with a '0' it doesn't work. Any help?

```
print ("""Here's how the program will work. You need to get your binary number ready.
        if it is 8 bit, split it into four, because thats how hexadecimal works. Make sure all your conversions
        are slip into '4' bits like this:
        01001101 will turn into:
        0100 ,and then 1101""")
time.sleep(6)
print ("""So, for example, the program will ask you for your binary number. Like this:
        Enter your binary number here:
        Then you put in your number, like this:
        Enter your binary number here: 0100
        Lastly, the program will give you your hexadecimal number, then ask you if you would
        like to do another conversion in this area, or end program.""")
time.sleep(6)
HEXADECIMAL = int(input("Please enter your binary number here:   "))                         
if HEXADECIMAL == 0000:
    print ("Your hexadecimal value is 0")
if HEXADECIMAL == 0001:
    print ("Your hexadecimal value is 1")
if HEXADECIMAL == 0010:
    print ("Your hexadecimal value is 2")
if HEXADECIMAL == 0011:
    print ("Your hexadecimal value is 3")
if HEXADECIMAL == 0100:
    print ("Your hexadecimal value is 4")
if HEXADECIMAL == 0101:
    print ("Your hexadecimal value is 5")
if HEXADECIMAL == 0110:
    print ("Your hexadecimal value is 6")
if HEXADECIMAL == 0111:
    print ("Your hexadecimal value is 7")
if HEXADECIMAL == 1000:
    print ("Your hexadecimal value is 8")
if HEXADECIMAL == 1001:
    print ("Your hexadecimal value is 9")
if HEXADECIMAL == 1010:
    print ("Your hexadecimal value is A")
if HEXADECIMAL == 1011:
    print ("Your hexadecimal value is B")
if HEXADECIMAL == 1100:
    print ("Your hexadecimal value is C")
if HEXADECIMAL == 1101:
    print ("Your hexadecimal value is D")
if HEXADECIMAL == 1110:
    print ("Your hexadecimal value is E")
if HEXADECIMAL == 1111:
    print ("Your hexadecimal value is F")
```

You can try to run this code and start with, for example, 0110, but it will not convert. Any help?

Comment: You are converting the user input to an `int`. `int` do not start with a leading zero. Just keep the user input as a string and do your tests by comparing to strings.

Comment: First of all, it's `BINARY`, not `HEXADECIMAL`.

Comment: The `int`  cast does not work correctly. Keep it as a string !

Comment: Not an answer. but hope you know a `hex()` function exists in python?

Comment: When I keep it as a string, the program says it is an 'invalid token', and skovordikin, this is BINARY to HEXADECIMAL converter

Comment: I just tried to keep it as a string, everything works fine. Just replace your input by `HEXADECIMAL = input("Please enter your binary number here:   ")`, and then do your tests against strings, like `if HEXADECIMAL == '0000':`. Side notes: 1) using caps for a variable name is bad practice, and 2) you should use `elif` for all the cases after the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to use the `if/else` statements evertime. There is a cool way you can use `int()` in python, if you using a string, `int()` function can directly convert it to any base for you.

```
HEXADECIMAL = str(input())

base = 16 # for Hex and 2 for binary
msg = "Your hexadecimal value is"
print (msg, int(HEXADECIMAL, base))
```

This will do it for you. But if you want to stick with your method than you should probably add a `0b` as in `0b0010` before the binary and do stuff, leading zeroes are illegal, `0010` is illegal.

Comment: so where do I put it in my program?

Comment: replace everything after the second `time.sleep(6)` with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

When you input an integer starting with an leading 0, python interprets it as being in base 8:

```
a = 0110
print a
```

will output

```
72
```

Therefore, drop the leading 0 in your input, or remove them before casting `int()` on it

Answer (score -1):

replace,

```
HEXADECIMAL = int(input("Please enter your binary number here:   "))
```

with,

```
temp = input("Please enter your binary number here:   ")                       
HEXADECIMAL = int (temp)
```

plus remove sleep time if there is an error.

Comment: The two blocks of code you have posted are functionally equivalent and neither solve the original question.

Comment: This doesn't change anything, it doesn't make any sense.